# can't creat vector of thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I would like to create a thread vector, but I get this error:

```
g++ -pthread test.cpp
 In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/vector:66,
                  from parcour.hpp:4,
                  from test.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::thread\*, std::vector<std::thread> >; _ForwardIterator = std::thread*]’: /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:307:37:
   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::thread*, std::vector<std::thread> >; _ForwardIterator = std::thread*; _Tp = std::thread]’ /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:555:31:
   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>]’ test.cpp:7:7:
   required from here /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:127:72: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
   127 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
```

In this code I try to generate cars's thread:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class Voiture{
    public:
        void avancer();
};

class Carrefour{
protected:
    typedef std::thread X;
    std::vector<X> voituresWE;   
public:
    friend class Generateur;
};

class Generateur{
    Carrefour carrefour;
public: 
    Generateur(Carrefour a): carrefour(a){}

    void generation(){
        while(1){
            Voiture voiture();
            carrefour.voituresWE.push_back(std::thread(&Voiture::avancer, voiture));
        }
    }
};
```

Il semblerait que le problème vient du type thread qui n'est pas accepté dans ce cas dans le vecteur.

Comment: can you please get rid of those backslashes? We need to copy paste your code into your compiler and we can't do that with your current code. Furthermore you need to provide a [MRE]

Comment: Note that according to `In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/vector:66, from parcour.hpp:4`, the problem may be in `parcour.hpp`.

Comment: Thank you for removing the backslashes! Now you need to create a [MRE]. We don't have the definitions of Parcour, Voiture etc. Please don't include the full code. Just a minimal skeleton to replicate the error you are getting.

Comment: Storing `&voiture` for later use is going to be a disaster. You need to be more careful with object lifetimes.

Answer (score 4):

There is still crucial information missing from your code, but I think my crystal ball is working today:

```
Gnerateur
{
   Carrefour carrefour;
   Generateur(Carrefour &a): carrefour(a) {}
//                                    ^
//                                    copy
}
```

Here you attempt to copy `a` of type `Carrefour` which is not copyable. Here's why:

- `std::thread` is not copyable so:
- `std::vector<std::thread>` is not copyable which makes:
- `Carrefour` not copyable because it contains `std::vector<std::thread>` data members (and doesn't have a user-defined copy constructor)

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @atrixe144 first of all you need to create a [mre] otherwise we have to guess. Second of all *what* doesn't solve the problem? I haven't offered a solution in my answer, I just pointed what is the cause of your error.  I can't know what you changed and how that affected the code.